# Key "catTitle" for array with keys "0" does not exist in EagleShopBundle:global:product.html.twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I'm trying to join two tables and print a value in twig template but I'm having this issue.

This is my Controller action.

```
/**
     * @Route("products/display/{id}")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function displayAction($id) {

        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

        $qb->select('p', 'pc.catTitle')
                ->from('EagleShopBundle:Products', 'p')
                ->leftJoin('EagleShopBundle:ProductCategory', 'pc', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'pc.id = p.category')
                ->where($qb->expr()->eq('p.id', '?5'))
                ->setParameter(5, $id);

        $product = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

        return $this->render("EagleShopBundle:global:product.html.twig", array(
                    'product' => $product,
                    'image_path' => '/bundles/eagleshop/images/'
        ));
    }
```

This is my twig file line related to the issue,

```
<small class="pr_type">{{product.catTitle}}</small>
```

But instead of printing 'catTitle' I'm having this issue,

> Key "catTitle" for array with keys "0" does not exist in
>   EagleShopBundle:global:product.html.twig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple: `getResult()` returns an array of objects, even if there is only one. If you are expecting that this query would return only one object use `getOneOrNullResult()`. But after that and before you are displaying results you need to check if smth is returned (for example: `product instanceof Products`) or null is returned.